# Вывод карточек товара на странице (Woocommerce)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Добрый день.
Занимаюсь вопросом вывода полных карточек товара на отдельной странице, но пока не пришел к какому-то решению. Необходимо на главной странице вывести подряд карточки нескольких товаров, но не миниатюрами, а так, как они отображаются, когда заходишь внутрь (т.е. когда используется шаблон вывода content-single-product.php). Главная страница реализована с помощью King Composer. Может какой-нибудь шорткод сделать для этого? Или еще какие-нибудь варианты реализации?

Comment: Сделайте шорткод, внутри которого будете подключать content-single-product.php. Нормальное решение. И кстати, а чем не устраивают стандартные шорткоды WooCommerce https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/ ?

Comment: Да, в итоге сделал свой виджет на основе стандартного виджета Woocommerce, который выводит товары списком. Переделал внутри вывод этого списка, включив в него шаблон content-single-product.php.